# How can I attach a volume to a Windows instance on Amazon EC2?

Tags: windows-server-2003, amazon-ec2

I have attached one volume to a Windows Server 2003 instance on Amazon EC2.

The status of the instance is shown as available, but I'm unable to see the drive on my server.

Comment: This question contains very little information, so you won't get a specific answer.  Please restate your question with more details of your environment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the disk and give it a partition. See the [second half of this guide](http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/01/attaching-an-ebs-volume-to-ec2/).

Comment: The disk should show up in the Drive Manager tool in windows even before it has been formated or partitioned.   In my experience it does.